# Is it ideal to consume a JavaScript library from a native mobile SDK?

Tags: javascript, java, android, ios, objective-c

Let's say we have this JavaScript code:

```
const add = (m, n) => m + n;
```

Now imagine it has been bundled by webpack into a single file, or accessible via URL on a CDN. Thus, you would only need that file to run this function on a browser or in NodeJS.

Now imagine you have a mobile app (either Android or iOS) that needs to run that bundled-up function *without reimplementing it*. Thus you need to run JavaScript code in Java or Kotlin or Objective C or iOS.

Some further constraints:

1. You cannot use WebView
2. This native code, including the parts that run JS, will be bundled into an SDK
3. The SDK needs to be consumable by any native app, not tying them down to any specific library
4. The logic in the JavaScript function is core to the mobile app

Is this possible? Even if it is possible, is it advisable?

---

A small bit of background to this question and why I'm asking it. We have two mobile SDKs (Android and iOS) which can be consumed either natively or by React Native. We also plan to reimplement the app on the desktop via Electron.

There is logic that all three platforms have in common, and that is currently written as a JavaScript library. Obviously, the Electron desktop app is able to consume it. Similarly, the React Native app has no problem in running it.

But we want to put that logic in the mobile SDK now, and I've been told not to use WebView. Is this task at all possible?

Comment: From what I understand, to run your common JS you definitely need wrapper for different platforms ( RN for mobile and Electron for desktop). You can have all your re-usable logic as node modules ( add and others ) and the these platform projects and use this. I think this is pretty neat.

Comment: @ShobhitChittora Unfortunately, I don't think you can embed RN into your SDK without also forcing the consuming apps to use RN. Please correct me if I'm wrong. The ideal scenario would be to have a portable mobile SDK that any native app can use. I've added this to the question.

Comment: Well Unfortunately! I don't think that's possible. You will have to have a Native SDK with the core functionality and RN wrapper over it for your consumer using RN.